# How I can get process path or pid from consent process (UAC)

Tags: c++, windows, uac

When I launch an application which requires UAC elevation, I see the UAC consent window, which is shown by the process "consent.exe".

I'm trying to determine the path or process ID of the application that is being launched.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: Still unclear, I'm afraid.  Are you trying to find (a) the path of the executable that will be launched with elevated privilege, if the user approves it; or (b) the path or pid of the process that tried to launch the executable that needs elevated privilege?

Comment: As a specific example: suppose I double-click on diskpart.exe, making a UAC consent dialog appear.  Did you want to find (a) the path to diskpart.exe, or (b) the process running Windows Explorer?

Comment: Why do you care? Is your plan to hack that file so you can steal admin privileges?

Comment: @Maxim Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. While the UAC **Consent** dialog is present, your screen is dimmed, and you cannot do anything else.

You have no choice but to dismiss the Consent dialog.